# Can I get the visitor's router name or MAC address?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Can I get the visitor's router name or MAC address? So that I can search his location in the streets?

Edit: Will Java or Flash help me?

Answer (score 4):

No. that information is not exposed by webbrowsers.

If you want location information you have to base it off either:

- [the geolocation api](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API)
- the IP address that a request (made by the browser to your server or the server of a third party geo location service) comes from